# Sum of Object based on Data Validation through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Objective: Sum of Object (similar# post) based on Similar Specific Tag (a data validation has been used).

Here is the screenshot:

This is the data after filter and conditions:
[image]

This is what the output should be:
[image]

For Example: So, when "Tag" is selected "Research Investment Banking" the output should be Sum of "# similar posts" that is 10 + 35 + 14 = 59

Since I'm not great with VBA. I was wondering if AutoFilter would work or SumIf?

```
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Raw").Range("$A$1:$E$23").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    Region
```

I've written this code:     'filtering data as per Tag

```
Dim Tag As String

Tag = Sheets("Raw").Range("I1")

Range("D2").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$23").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
 Tag
```

But it's missing the previous code which is to filter data based on Selected Region.

```
'filtering data as per region

Dim Region As String

Region = Sheets("Raw").Range("H1")

Range("E2").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Raw").Range("$A$1:$E$23").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    Region
```

Comment: Do you want a report with the Sum of object (similar #post) for every Region in your above table?
Or Do you want to have the sum of objects based on the how you change the filter ?

Comment: Hi Kanike, here is the condition that need to be True - Date = Today's date, Tag = Same ( in this case "Research Investment Banking") and Region = UK & EMEA ( in this case). So yes, it will be based on the filter I chose.  You let me know if you want the whole VBA code to get a picture. Thanks!

Comment: I've written this code:

Comment: If you want the sum of posts on the fly, based on region & tag, then using Pivots is easy and writing VBA can be avoided. And change the pivot filters based on your requirement. You can follow the steps below, answered by @Ethun_Hunt

Comment: These selection are to be made in the background and final output is in a different sheet in a form of Table. Hence, can't use Pivot. Plus this a client requirement. But not a problem. I got the fix but just making some changes to the existing code it's working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: This step resolved the problem:     'filtering data as per Tag & Region
    
    Dim Tag As String
    Dim Region As String

    Tag = Sheets("Raw").Range("I1")
    Region = Sheets("Raw").Range("H1")

    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Sheets("Raw").Range("$A$1:$E$23").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
     Tag
    Sheets("Raw").Range("$A$1:$E$23").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        Region

Comment: If it is resolved then great. Do let know if you face further difficulties

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivot table.

Insert > Pivot Table > Select All data and Change location of pivot tabel accordingly

In the values field put the "# similar post"
In rows field put the "Tag"

and you will get output as follows:
[Click here to see the output of the Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqXt0.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the resolution:

```
'filtering data as per Tag & Region

Dim Tag As String
Dim Region As String

Tag = Sheets("Raw").Range("I1")
Region = Sheets("Raw").Range("H1")

Range("D1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Raw").Range("$A$1:$E$23").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
 Tag
Sheets("Raw").Range("$A$1:$E$23").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    Region
```

Comment: What new have you done in this code? 
How is it different from the above code ?
If I am not understanding wrong, you have collated both pieces of code (Tag& Region) as one